# ScriptSig Conversion in Python

Tags: bitcoind, raw-transaction, input-script, encoding

I'm trying to convert a scriptsig into bytes so that I can better extract R & S values, but when I try and convert, I'm missing some of elements that should be there, like x30 for example.

```
scriptsig = '473044022015d8e1ba1d7fa0bd065f3da2d91d71d12890ff4d9a655161783504714c8b06a3022007d71d93d79039d73fc47ab9787128b7a6d7449e72688f0cf6dc175cfa90755d0121037ab79af7f21e54e03297fc9447952bfacedc57dcebd802eb19ba75636ad1fd5e'

import binascii
bytes1 = binascii.unhexlify(scriptsig) #doesn't work
bytes2 = scriptsig.decode('base64') #doesn't work

The output:
bytes1
'G0D\x02 \x15\xd8\xe1\xba\x1d\x7f\xa0\xbd\x06_=\xa2\xd9\x1dq\xd1(\x90\xffM\x9aeQax5\x04qL\x8b\x06\xa3\x02 \x07\xd7\x1d\x93\xd7\x909\xd7?\xc4z\xb9xq(\xb7\xa6\xd7D\x9erh\x8f\x0c\xf6\xdc\x17\\\xfa\x90u]\x01!\x03z\xb7\x9a\xf7\xf2\x1eT\xe02\x97\xfc\x94G\x95+\xfa\xce\xdcW\xdc\xeb\xd8\x02\xeb\x19\xbaucj\xd1\xfd^'

bytes2
'\xe3\xbd\xf4\xe3\x8d6\xdbMyw\xc7\xb5m\xad]\xed\xf6\xb4m\xdd:\xe5\xfd\xddkg}\xd5\xde\xf5w]\xbc\xf7G\xdf\xe1\xdfZ\xeb\x9eu\xeb^\xfc\xdf\x9d8\xef^\x1c\xf1\xbd:k}6\xdbM;w\xbd]\xf7w{\xf7M\xfdw\xbd\xdfs\x8e\xdao\xde\xfc\xef]\xbco\xb6\xbaw\xbe8\xf5\xee\xf6\xeb\xcf\x1f\xd1\xc7\xfau\xcd{\xe5\xc7\xda\xf7N\xf9\xe5\xdd5\xdb]7\xed\xa6\xfb\xf5\xa7\xfb\x7fm^\xe7\x87\xb4\xdfo{}\xcfx\xe3\xbfy\xd9\xb7\xdaq\xe7\\\xe7\xb7\\y\xb7|\xd3g\x9b\xd7\xd6\xda\xef\x9e\xb7\xe9\xa7u}\xde^'
```

Once I got the right format I was going to use asn1decoder to parse for x30 and then extract R and S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x30 is there it's '0' in ascii (second character in your bytes1)

```
>>> b'\x30'
b'0'
```

You also want to extract the signature from the scriptSig before passing it to a decoder, right now it contains both the signature and the public key.